# Nuxt constant is assigned a value but never used

Tags: vuejs2, constants, nuxt.js

I have an Nuxt (Vue2) application which throws me an error:

> c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\test\dynamic_stores\campaign.js
> 1436:12  error  'campaign' is assigned a value but never used
> no-unused-vars   1438:12  error  'campaign' is assigned a value but
> never used  no-unused-vars   1441:18  error  'campaign' is not defined
> no-undef

```js
if( share_token ) {
  const campaign = await this.$api.campaigns.getSharedCampaign(share_token);
} else {
  const campaign = await this.$api.campaigns.getCampaign(state.id);
}

const data = campaign.data;
```

Can somebody tell me please what is wrong with this code? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line throw an error since campaign is used out of scope of the if statement?

Comment: You could maybe use some JS basics course (eg. from Wes Bos) to strengthen your skills. Will help you in the mid/long run. Diving too fast into a framework will be pretty difficult if your foundation is not rock solid.

Comment: @kissu How is this problem related to the JS basic skills. This is valid JS and I am pretty sure also valid Vue code.

Comment: This is related to basic programming knowledge (scope of a function) as explained in the answer below. So, even if it is "valid", it is totally unrelated to either Vue or Nuxt.

Comment: 'campaign' is assigned a value but never used is related to the basic programing knowledge? I dont think so. This is not the function scope. This is the condition scope which is not included in JS.  it is totally unrelated to JS as you wrote above.

Comment: This **is** basic programming knowledge. I mean, you do have this in a lot of languages (and no, it has nothing to do with JS' hoisting). Reference here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Block_scope Or just google any CS degree/language. It's okay to start somewhere, no issue with that. This is still some basic stuff that you may want to learn at some point if you want to have less issues in the long run. Not saying this to bash but to help btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `campaign` outside of the `if-else` statement in order to access it outside of the `if-else` statement.

Example:

```js
let campaign;
if (share_token) {
    campaign = await this.$api.campaigns.getSharedCampaign(share_token);
} else {
    campaign = await this.$api.campaigns.getCampaign(state.id);
}
const data = campaign.data;
```

Comment: Yes I know but I dont want to mess the code with it.

Comment: What do you mean by `mess` here? It being defined in the upper scope is totally fine here. I mean, you could write it in several ways but this is totally **not** messy.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a method, you can return API calls and you can use response as a result.

```
handleFetch(){
    if(share_token) {
      return this.$api.campaigns.getSharedCampaign(share_token);
    } else {
      return this.$api.campaigns.getCampaign(state.id);
    }
}
```

thank you can use in template or somewhere else with:

```
handleFetch()
```